# Find all elements with the same value in a vector, then erase all of them out of the vector

Tags: c++, stdvector, erase

The problem is that I need to find all elements with the same value in a vector, do something with them, then erase all of them out of the vector. Keep doing that until the vector is empty.

```
vector<unsigned> L;
vector<unsigned>::iterator it, it2, it3;
vector<unsigned> vec;
unsigned Z;

// populate the vector (1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4)
for(unsigned i = 1; i <= 4; ++i)
   L.push_back(i);
for(unsigned i = 2; i <= 4; i = i + 2)
   L.push_back(i);

it = L.begin();
while(it != L.end() -1){
  cout<< "*it = " << *it << endl;
  Z=0;
  vec.clear();

  it2 = it + 1;
  cout<< "*it2 = " << *it2 << endl;

  while(it2 != L.end()){
     cout << "Loop *it2 = " << *it2 <<endl;
     if(*it == *it2){
        vec.push_back(*it);
        L.erase(it2);  // iterator automatically points to the next element
        cout<< "after erase(it2), *it2 = " << *it2 << endl;
        continue;
     }
     ++it2;
  }
// do something (here I calculate the average)
  for(it3 = vec.begin(); it3 != vec.end(); ++it3)
     Z = Z+ *it3;

  Z= Z/vec.size();

  cout<< "Z = " << Z << endl << endl;
  L.erase(it); // iterator automatically points to the next element
}
```

The output is:

```
*it = 1
*it2 = 2
Loop *it2 = 2
Loop *it2 = 3
Loop *it2 = 4
Loop *it2 = 2
Loop *it2 = 4
```

Then it stops working

If I populate the vector with this code

```
// populate the vector (1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3)
for(unsigned i = 1; i <= 4; ++i)
   L.push_back(i);
for(unsigned i = 1; i <= 4; i = i + 2)
   L.push_back(i);
```

Then the output is

```
*it = 1
*it2 = 2
Loop *it2 = 2
Loop *it2 = 3
Loop *it2 = 4
Loop *it2 = 1
after erase(it2), *it2 = 3
Loop *it2 = 3
Z = 1

*it = 2
*it2 = 3
Loop *it2 = 3
Loop *it2 = 4
Loop *it2 = 3
```

It stops working here

I know there is something wrong in the second while loop but I can't figure out what it is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What values are you trying to erase?  It seems that all you really need is to use one, maybe two STL algorithm functions instead of all of this code you've written.

Comment: STL algorithm is not enough for this problem. I am trying to find all the same-valued-elements in the vector, do something with them, then delete them all from the vector. This problem is a simplification of my bigger problem. Let's say the element is not a number, but a `struct` of `Point(X, Y, Z)`. Hundreds of Points are in the vector. There are many Points which have the same X, Y but different Z. I want to find all of these Points, then take the average of Z. The result is a new coordinate I desire. While coding I end up with the problem stated above.

Comment: *This problem is a simplification of my bigger problem.*  -- Exactly -- why is it you can't use the algorithm function(s)?  All you've described is a more complex predicate function (see my answer).  Just write a predicate that partitions the elements (if you take a look at my solution) -- it doesn't matter how simple or complex your issue is -- as long as you can determine what is or is not erased is all that is required.

Comment: Please see this: http://ideone.com/c6KeqN It detects the points with the same x,y, but different z. Then a partition is done, and takes the average of the z's that have the same x,y. Then it erases those duplicates. The only difference between the simple example and the one you just mentioned in your comment is the partitioning -- yes, it takes a little bit of thinking because it is a more complex scenario, but the best thing about it is that is all we concentrate on -- writing the partitioning predicate. There are no complex while loops, etc. – PaulMcKenzie 8 hours ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to

1. Process duplicates and then
2. Erase them

there is a much easier solution to this, and that is to use [std::stable_partition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition), along with a `std::set`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> L = { 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4 };
    std::set<int> tempSet;
    //...
    // partition the elements, unique items on left, duplicates on right
    auto divider = stable_partition(L.begin(), L.end(), [&](int n)
    {
        // return true if item is not in the set, false otherwise
        return tempSet.insert(n).second;
    });

    // do something with the duplicates, for example, print them
    cout << "Here are the dups:\n";
    copy(divider, L.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));

    // get the average

    // get number of duplicates  
    size_t numDups = std::distance(divider, L.end());  
    double avg = 0.0;

    // compute average using std::accumulate
    if ( numDups > 0 ) 
       avg = std::accumulate(divider, L.end(), 0.0) / numDups;
    cout << "\nThe average of the duplicates is: " << avg << "\n";

    // erase the duplicates
    L.erase(divider, L.end());

    // print the updated vector now
    cout << "\n\nHere is the resulting vector:\n";
    copy(L.begin(), L.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
}
```

[Live Example, C++ 14](http://ideone.com/P0o7kb)

Here is the same code, but using C++ 03 (for those without C++11 / 14):

[Live Example, C++ 03](http://ideone.com/vVmmKO)

Note there are no loops in the code above.  Everything is done by an algorithm function.  Partitioning, average computation, erasing, etc., are all performed with no loops.

Basically we test each item to see if the item exists in the set.  If it does, then it will go to the right of the partition, if not, then the item goes to the left of the partition.

The return value `divider` is an iterator to the element that is the "dividing line" in the partition.  Once the items are partitioned, then we can process them easily by using `divider` to tell us where the "good" items are and where the "about to be erased" items are.

BTW, this worked the first time I compiled it successfully -- the one major reason for this "luck" in getting it to work quickly is that the algorithm functions just plain work when given the correct parameters (and if the predicate function is written correctly).  Erasing items, moving items, etc. in a container, especially a sequence container such as vector, is almost always covered by usage of 1, 2, or 3 algorithm functions.

Comment: Your lambda may be simplified to `return tempSet.insert(n).second;`

Comment: Thanks.  Added the simplification and changed sample program.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, which was inspired by [PaulMcKenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3133316/paulmckenzie)'s code (please don't mind my re-using some of your lines). Just like him I didn't use any handwritten loops, but made use of STL's algorithms, which one should always consider first.

In my solution I only use another container of exactly the same type and only two simple algorithms: `std::remove_if` and `std::find`. This way the code makes the intention a little bit clearer: find duplicates and remove them. Also note the use of `std::move` that should come in handy when having a container of something more complex than `int`. In that case one may have to consider using `std::find_if` of course.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> L = { 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4 };
    using cont = decltype(L);
    using vt = cont::value_type;

    // find duplicates and move them to separate container
    cont D;
    D.reserve(L.size());
    D.swap(L);
    D.erase(std::remove_if(D.begin(), D.end(), [&L] (vt& value)
    {
        if (L.cend() == std::find(L.cbegin(), L.cend(), value))
        {
            L.emplace_back(std::move(value));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }), D.end());

    // do something with the duplicates, for example, print them
    std::cout << "Here are the dups:\n";
    std::copy(D.cbegin(), D.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<vt>(std::cout, " "));

    // print the vector now
    std::cout << "\n\nHere is the resulting vector:\n";
    std::copy(L.begin(), L.end(), std::ostream_iterator<vt>(std::cout, " "));

    return 0;
}
```

See it in action [here](http://cpp.sh/3io3).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `erase` call.  `erase` does not automatically update the iterator; it *returns* the iterator to the next element.  To fix it, you need to use

```
it2 = L.erase(it2);
```

and later

```
it = L.erase(it);
```

Comment: `erase` does make the iterator point to the next element of the deleted element.

Comment: @Thanh For vectors `erase` invalidates the iterator that is erased and all the iterators that follow.  To be compliant with the definition of `erase` and avoid Undefined Behavior, you must assign the return value from `erase` back to your iterator.

Comment: You are half-right about the invalidation of iterator. If we call `L.erase(it)`, `it` will point to the next element and invalidate all the iterators after `it`, but not `it` itself and the iterators before `it`. Basically, your answer `it = L.erase(it)` and my code `L.erase(it)` are the same thing (I tried it in the code). Anyway, I found and posted the solution myself. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<unsigned> L;
vector<unsigned>::iterator it, it2, it3;
vector<unsigned> vec;
unsigned Z;

// populate the vector (1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4)
for(unsigned i = 1; i <= 4; ++i)
    L.push_back(i);
for(unsigned i = 2; i <= 4; i = i + 2)
    L.push_back(i);

std::set<unsigned int> myset;
for(it = L.begin(); it != L.end(); ++it){
    myset.insert(*it);
}

for(std::set<unsigned int>::iterator iter = myset.begin();
    iter != myset.end(); ++iter){
    std::cout << "element = " << *iter << std::endl;
    Z += *iter;
}
std::cout << "sum = " << Z << std::endl;
Z = Z/myset.size();

std::cout<< "Average value = " << Z << std::endl;
L.clear();
```

Comment: Note that `set` can directly be initialized with iterators: `std::set<unsigned int> myset(L.begin(), L.end());`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out the solution for my own question. The question is

1. We have a vector `L` that contains many duplicated elements.
2. We need to find all the dup elements
3. Do something with the dup elements

My method is to use 2 iterators on `L`, say `it` and `it2`. `it` is kept at the beginning of `L`, while `it2` will go through the vector. If `*it` and `*it2` have the same value, then we will put `*it2` into a temporary vector `vec`. Then, we `L.erase(it2)`. `it2` will keep moving till the end of `L`, collect all the dup elements into `vec` and delete them from `L`. When `it2` reach the end of `L`, we call `L.erase(it)`. After that, the process continues until the vector `L` is empty.

Here is the code that I modified. The most important thing to note is the condition in the `while`. I use `while(it < L.end())` instead of `while(it != L.end())` because when we erase an element, the iterator will somehow go pass the condition `!=`.

I am using an old compiler (older than C++0x) for I don't want to mess with the environment right now. Thus, it will be safe for anyone to use my code.

```
vector<unsigned> L;
vector<unsigned>::iterator it, it2, it3, it4;
vector<unsigned> vec; //temporary variable to store matched elements
float Z;

// populate the vector (1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3)
for(unsigned i = 1; i <= 4; ++i)
  L.push_back(i);
for(unsigned i = 1; i <= 4; i = i + 2)
  L.push_back(i);


it = L.begin();
while(it < L.end()){
  cout<< "*it = " << *it << endl;
  Z=0;
  vec.clear();

  vec.push_back(*it);
  if(L.size() == 1){
     cout << "Last element of vector = " << *it <<endl;
     goto Loop1;
  }
  else
     it2 = it + 1;

  while(it2 < L.end()){
     cout << "Loop *it2 = " << *it2 <<endl;   //debug
     if(*it == *it2){
        vec.push_back(*it2);
        L.erase(it2);  // iterator automatically points to the next element
        cout<< "after erase(it2), *it2 = " << *it2 << endl;   //debug
        continue;
     }
     ++it2;
  }

  Loop1:

  for(it3 = vec.begin(); it3 != vec.end(); ++it3)
     Z = Z+ *it3;

  Z= Z/vec.size();

  cout<< "Z = " << Z << endl ;

  if(L.empty()) break;

  L.erase(it); // iterator automatically points to the next element

  //debug
  cout<< endl <<  "new vector = "; 
  for(it4 = L.begin(); it4 != L.end(); ++it4) 
     cout << *it4 << ' ';
  cout << endl;
}
```

@PaulMcKenzie: I took me a while to catch on with your writing style in C++14 and the use of the STL functions which I am not familiar with. Your code is at very high level and it is hard for beginner. Anyway, I chose it as best answer for your contribution. I really learned a lot from you. Thank you for your quick responses.

Comment: Actually, the code I wrote is not hard at all.  It is more declarative "partition, accumulate, erase" than your code.  In other words, the code itself "says what it does".   Without comments and actually running your solution, it would not be as easy, even for a seasoned C++ programmer, to figure out exactly what your code does.   Also, the use of `goto` would not be looked too highly on by many, so beware.  As to C++ 03, you could write my solution using C++ 03, since the algorithm functions exist there, just that the predicate would be a function object instead of a lambda.

Comment: Added C++ 03 version to my answer.